# android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.showKey(KeyboardView.java:925) CharSequence.length() on a null object reference at

Tags: java, android, keyboard, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

``Hi developers I am working on a keyboard app. I'm facing an exception that I can't detect because it's on the keyboard end. If anyone knows about this exception please help.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.showKey(KeyboardView.java:936)
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.access$100(KeyboardView.java:75)
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView$1.handleMessage(KeyboardView.java:382)
```

Comment: basically what you're having is aNullPointerException. You'll need to check your actual code to figure out what where and why

Comment: @Stultuske android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView is a Java built-in class. In my original code I didn't call this method from anywhere. That's why I couldn't detect the null pointer exception.

Comment: go through the rest of the stacktrace. somewhere, it'll point to your code